# Checking if a tablecolumn contains a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Any code for checking a table-column's value? Lets say we have a table `submittedpictures` and it contains a column called `isFinalPicture`. There are 5 records, but only one of them has `isFinalPicture == true`. The others are all false.

How can I check this?

I already tried something like

```
<% if @user.games.rounds.submitted_pictures.isFinalPicture.include?(true) %>
```

But it didnt really work, and I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
<% if @user.games.rounds.submitted_pictures.where(:isFinalPicture => true).any? %>
```